# Listing all the ideals of a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I have no idea how to answer this question.

> Let *R* be the quotient ring $\mathbb Q[X]/(X^3 + X^2 + X + 1)$. How to list all the ideals of *R*? And how to determine whether each ideal is prime, maximal, or neither?

Comment: Another hint: $1+x+x^2+x^3=(x^4-1)/(x-1)$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\mathbb Q$ is a field so $\mathbb Q[x]$ is a PID.  What does the correspondence theorem say about ideals and what does that translate to when the ideals are principal?